# Knockout Mapping doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having troubles using Knockout Mapping.

I have a FormBuilderViewModel, containing a bunch of functions including loading and saving data. The first line (after self = this) is the following:

`this.form = ko.mapping.fromJS({blueprint_identifier: undefined, name: undefined, description: undefined, pages : []})`

I initialise 'this.form' with 3 meta variables and 1 array.

Then, I load the data (also in FormBuilderViewModel):

`ko.mapping.fromJSON(allData, {}, self.form);`

The variable `allData` comes from the AJAX request and contains exactly this:
`{"blueprint_identifier":1347437911,"name":"test","description":"test","pages":[]}`

The problem is: the loaded JSON never appears on my page. The output of `console.log(this.form)` AFTER loading the data is empty. Here's the entire script (apart from the functions etc.):

```
var FormBuilderViewModel = function(data){
    var self = this;

    this.form = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                   blueprint_identifier: undefined, 
                   name: undefined, 
                   description: undefined, 
                   pages : []
                })

    $.getJSON("x", function(allData) {
        if(){
            console.log("I'm here");
            ko.mapping.fromJSON(allData, {}, self.form);
        }else{
            // not relevant
        }
    });
    console.log(self.form); 
};
```

Output is 'I'm here' (so we get to the loading point), then the empty 'form' object.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functioning fiddle that does what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/Cm4xS/

I initialize form with an empty observable, and then load it when the AJAX call returns.  By using the `with` binding I won't attempt to show the form until it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` function works `async` so when you call `console.log(self.form)` mapping is not finished. 
To see your object in the console output move log operation into success function:

```
$.getJSON("x", function(allData) {
    if(){
        console.log("I'm here");
        ko.mapping.fromJSON(allData, {}, self.form);
        console.log(self.form);
    }else{
        // not relevant
    }
});
```

Try to use `ko.mapping.fromJS` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJSON` because `allData` is not string as `fromJSON` expected:

```
$.getJSON("x", function(allData) {
    if(){
        console.log("I'm here");
        ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, {}, self.form);
        console.log(self.form);
    }else{
        // not relevant
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't appear on my page either. self.form never gets changed. console.log(self.form) within the success function gives the same result.